# Simple backbone.js model connection

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, bind

I'm starting out with backbone and I'm trying to create a simple view that alerts whenever my model changes. Right now the initialize function in the view is being called, but the render function is not being called when my model changes (my model is being changed).
I've attempted two ways of binding to the change event (in the initialize function and the events property). I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

The #jsonPreview id exists in the html.

```
// Create the view
var JSONView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function(){
    this.bind("change", this.render);
  },

  render: function() {
    alert("change");
  },
  events:
  {
    "change":"render"
  }

});

// Create the view, and attach it to the model:
var json_view = new JSONView({ el: $("#jsonPreview"), model: documentModel });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are binding to the `change` event on the view rather than the view's model.  think you need to bind to the model event something like this:

```
initialize: function(){
  this.model.bind("change", this.render);
},
```

Comment: Still the same result - render doesn't get called :(

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone: Yes it does (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AWesV/), what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to compare it to what I'm doing and see where the difference is. I'll be back shortly, thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem was because my set wasn't being recognized as making a change to the model - something to do with me setting an array instead of a single variable.

Comment: @muistooshort The problem was I was getting an array, and expecting it to be a copy of the array, not the actual array - hence it wasn't triggering change when I set the array - since it was comparing itself to itself, oops!

Comment: This question is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909799/backbone-js-change-not-firing-on-model-change

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone: Ah, I see, the old "JavaScript has pointers even though they're not called pointers" problem.

Comment: @muistooshort Exactly. I did a quick workaround by doing a deep copy of what was returned from get by converting it to a JSON string and then parsing it. This will do for now since I'm only working on a prototype (I'll find a better solution when I have time). Thanks again.

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone: jQuery's [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) can do deep copies if you pass `true` as the first argument.