# Meteor package: Session.set not working at all

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have inside a Meteor package, a global function in a js file I add via `api.addFiles`:

```
showLayer = function(id) {
    var layers = Session.get('layers');
    layers[id] = true;
    Session.set('layers', layers);

    // just for testing - check if it worked
    var tmpLayers = Session.get('layers');
    alert('layers.id:' + layers[id] + ' tmpLayers.id:' + tmpLayers[id]);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var tmpLayers = Session.get('layers');
        alert('layers.id:' + layers[id] + ' tmpLayers.id:' + tmpLayers[id]);
    }, 1000);
};
```

Note that the `setTimeout` I am only using to give `Session` some time if there should be some optimisation delaying the change. The result is that `layers[id]` is set as it should but `tmpLayers[id]` is not, tested delayed and right after `set`.

No matter if I check delayed via `setTimeout` or right in place inside the function: the `Session.set` line does not seem to do *any* thing whatsoever!

Note that this is not a problem of not occurring reactivity - or at least I would not see how.

Comment: Did you add `api.use('session');` in your `package.js`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes - I am using `session` and `meteor-platform` which should include all others. I have now also added the non-delayed test code above to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short solution: use an { } instead of an [ ].**

I found a possible reason through this stack overflow question: [Javascript arrays and Meteor session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780116/javascript-arrays-and-meteor-session).

**However**: the solution provided there did *not* solve the problem for me. **What did solve it was to make the [ ] an { }.** No cloning needed, it worked out of the box. This issue I think might be a bug, but I could not easily reproduce it.