# How bind change event with view when in-array object's property changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

The following are some of my coffeescript code

```
class Floor extends Backbone.Model
    defaults:
        "array":[]

    initialize: ->
        a = []
        for i in [0..10] by 1
            tmp = {
                x: i*10,
                y: i*10
            }
            a.push(tmp)
        this.set('array', a)

class FloorView extends Backbone.View
    initialize: ->
        this.model.on('change:array', this.renderArray, this) 

    renderArray: ->
        console.log 'Do something'
        return this

floor1 = new Floor
floorView = new floorView({ model:floor1})
```

The following three lines are not fire the change event calling renderArray
method

```
array = floor1.get('array')
array[0].x = 1000;
floor1.set('array',array)
```

but the following code actually call the renderArray method

```
floor1.set('array',{});
```

is there any method to detect property changed of an object in an array?

or what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about it this way: "array" is a variable name that points to an array. When you do this:

```
floor1.set('array', []);
```

You are pointing "array" to a completely different array. However, when you do this:

```
array = floor1.get('array')
array[0].x = 1000;
floor1.set('array', array)
```

You are updating the array that "array" already points to. In other words, you are not changing the array that "array" points to. Instead, you are modifying a value within the existing array.

This Q&A has more backround: [Backbone.js : change not firing on model.change()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909799/backbone-js-change-not-firing-on-model-change)

And points out this work around:

```
array = floor1.get('array')
array[0].x = 1000;
floor1.set('array', array)
floor1.trigger('change:array')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the backbone change event is not looping to check if all properties in object or elements in array changes, but just check if address changed right?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would interprete it.