# Backbone Model array property change and change event listener not always firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I found something strange in Backbone using change events.
It's with an Model wich has an Array as property.
And if I get the property push a new value inside and set it back to the model the change event is not fired...

Here's a fully documented example:

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        numbers : []
    },

    initialize : function() {
        this.on('change:numbers', this.changedEvent);
    },

    changedEvent : function() {
        console.log('model has changed');
    }
});

var oTestModel = new TestModel();
    oTestModel.set('numbers', [2, 3, 4]);    // change:numbers Event is fired

var aNumbers = oTestModel.get('numbers');
    aNumbers.push(5);

oTestModel.set('numbers', aNumbers);    // change:numbers event is NOT fired BUT WHY???

// oTestModel.set('numbers', [2, 3, 4]); 
// If this line is not commented out change:numbers event is also fired

console.log(oTestModel.toJSON());  // Dumps out [2,3,4,5] Respective [2,3,4] if line above is not commented out
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

hesson is absolutely right about:

> Arrays in JavaScript are treated as pointers, so mutating the array will not change the pointer, and no "change" event is fired.

However, as an alternate solution (if you are also using underscore.js) you can just do:

```
var aNumbers = _.clone(oTestModel.get('numbers'));
aNumbers.push(5);

oTestModel.set('numbers', aNumbers); //Will trigger the changed:numbers event
```

As seen in the answer to this similar problem:
[Backbone.js : change not firing on model.change()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909799/backbone-js-change-not-firing-on-model-change)

This will duplicate the object instead of making it a reference, however nested objects or arrays will be only references.

Comment: Could there be a significant performance hit using `_.clone(..)` on a large object?

Comment: Yes, since you are adding custom code to workaround the issue, better add the code that triggers the event: `oTestModel.trigger('change:numbers', oTestModel, aNumbers)`

Comment: Depending on your event subscribers you might also need to trigger the general 'change' event `oTestModel.trigger('change', oTestModel)` or both to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in JavaScript are treated as pointers, so mutating the array will not change the pointer, and no "change" event is fired. Instead you need to setup a method in which you mutate the array, and in this method, you trigger your own custom event. For example:

```
mutateArray: function() {
    var numbers = this.get("numbers");
    numbers.push(5);
    this.trigger("mutatedarray");
    return this;
}
```

Note that because numbers is a pointer, it would be pointless to call set (no pun intended), since numbers is only a reference to the array. Then you can listen to changes by listening to the custom mutatedarray event like this:

```
this.on("mutatedarray", this.changedEvent, this);
```