# How to remove a backbone model from only one collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

We're hitting a fundamental problem with Backbone: if I add the same model to collections A and B `A.add()` and `B.add()`, and I then remove it from collection A with `A.remove()`, a remove event is triggered on the model which collection B hears, and so the model is removed from collection B as well.  Is there a preferred way around this default behavior?  Do we have to specify `{silent: true}` every single time we manipulate these collections, or is there a better way?

Thanks,
-mykle-

Comment: Could you clarify what you'd mean by _"the model is removed from collection B as well"_? Does your `"remove"` event listener removes the model from collection B or the model is removed automatically (without your action)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the change method on your model when you initialize it.

```
Ship = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name:'titanic',
        cas: new Array()
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('change:cas', this.notify, this);
        this.on('change', this.notify, this);
    },
    notify: function() {
        console.log('cas changed');
    },
    notifyGeneral: function() {
        console.log('general change');
    }
});
```

This is a good example of a model with two change events.  You will need to check the model's collection name and change or not change accordingly.  Here, you might do something like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.on('change', this.notify, this);
},
notify: function() {

    console.log('cas changed');
    if(this.collection.id = 'CollectionB'){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
}
```

Here's a good reference:

[Backbone.js : change not firing on model.change()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909799/backbone-js-change-not-firing-on-model-change)